# Guice: How to create HttpSessionProvider

Tags: java, guice, provider

I have a module below which is defined as a inner class of the Servlet.

```
private static abstract class TestModule extends AbstractModule 
implements Provider<HttpSession> {

    @Override 
    protected void configure( ) {
     bind(HttpSession.class).toProvider( TestModule.class );
    }
    @Override public abstract HttpSession get( );
}
```

Within the doGet() of the Servlet I created the Injector as below:

```
@Override 
protected void doGet( final HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse resp ) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector( new TestModule( ) {
        @Override 
        public HttpSession get( ) {
            return req.getSession( );
        } 
    });      
}
```

I get error:

> 1) No implementation for javax.servlet.http.HttpSession was bound.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you configure like this:

```
bind(HttpSession.class).toProvider( TestModule.class );
```

but the actual provider of HttpSession is that Anonymous inner class you create when creating your injector.

To solve this, simply use the ServletModule of Guice: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule

Comment: Is there a work around for this? Basically I need to create the implementation of Provider's get() when creating the injector within doGet() or doPost().

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But now its going to complain about HttpServletRequest not being bound.

Comment: @Mayumi As I said at the end of my post, not if you use the ServletModule which provides those. And actually I should come back on what I said, the ServletModule also provides an `HttpSession` provider.